# error when trying to add trust external domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

when am tryind to configure trust domain with wizzart i have this error message "The specified account already exists"

the both server are in

the both Domain are Windows Server 2003 Forest functional level.

the both Domain are Windows Server 2008 domain functional level.

can someone help, tanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the TDO object for the trust already exists in your environment. If you have just made the trust, you need to wait for this to replicate throughout both environments. If you have replication problems on either side, this can be a problem.